# Is it possible to create C# based plugins for QGIS (instead of Python)?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c#

My team has a lot of C# code that we've used for ArcGIS Add-in development.  We're thinking of porting some of these tools into QGIS as plugins using QT Designer.  However rewriting them with Python on the back-end isn't such a fun idea.  Is it possible to use C# on the back end instead?

Comment: You wish! (and so do I) there is a possibility of C++ plugins but they are *strongly discouraged*. The reason for this, as I understand it, is that QGIS is a platform independent program, it's the same source for Mac, Linux and MS Windows but C#/VB.net is MS Windows only. If **anyone knows of a C# API for QGIS I'd be VERY INTERESTED TOO**. There is a C# API for GDAL/OGR if that helps, it's hosted by Tamas Szekeres at http://www.gisinternals.com/ and I can personally attest that it works well.

Answer (score 5):

Currently no.  In the future, small maybe, I mean super small. A few reasons:

- We use SIP to generate the Python bindings from C++.  This is a tool that knows how to wrap the C++ API and expose it Python. Python can introp with C/C++ so this is really a wrapper library that does all the work to get from one place to the other.
- There is no said tool to do that for .NET.  There has been a few attempts at it but nothing production ready, nor anything that I could ever get running for basic examples.
- .NET on Linux while possible is also still a new thing with a whole host of other issues and isn't the same from my understanding as the normal .NET we have in Windows. It's it is a growing runtime as they port stuff over.

So that brings the question, why does MapServer/GDAL, etc have bindings for those but we don't. Simple answer they don't use Qt. They are plain C/C++ libraries (for the most part) and use SWIG. SWIG currently doesn't handle stuff Qt does (but seems people want it: https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/88 so maybe at some stage)